# mysql group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Service_ID   feedback  
31             1
32             1
33             1
```

I have the following query to find the sum:

```
SELECT Service_ID,SUM(consumer_feedback) FROM consumer5 group by Service_ID
```

I have to get the output as

```
31 1
32 1
33 1
```

I am getting it. But for my project I have 34, 35 also. I should get output as

```
31 1
32 1
33 1
34 0
35 0
```

Comment: Execute the select query separately and see whether your able to get the desired output and check any break statement in your code as i felt some more lines is missing around if() here.

Best thing would be debug the program.

Comment: I removed the JDBC part from your question. This has nothing to do with JDBC. It's a matter of writing the right SQL query. JDBC is *just* there to be able to execute SQL queries using Java. You would still have exactly the same problem if you execute it directly on the DB or using any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to outer join on a table of all service IDs. It will be something like this, though I am sure this syntax is a little bit wrong:

SELECT Service_ID, total FROM (SELECT Service_ID,SUM(consumer_feedback) AS total FROM  consumer5 group by Service_ID) OUTER JOIN service_ids ON Service_ID

Answer (score 0):

Please post the table information (structure query), so we can tell you more. Also please post the data as well where the id 34 and 35 appears.

if you have the data like in the following example then you will get the results for 34 and 35 as well:

```
31     1
32     1
33     1
34     0
35     0
```

If you have it like this, then you will get the result for 34 and 35 as well, but you will get NULL as sum:

```
31     1
32     1
33     1
34     null
35     null
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also be interested in reading about JOINS:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT service_id,
       SUM(IFNULL(feedback, 0))
FROM service_table
    LEFT JOIN feedback_table USING (service_id)
GROUP BY service_id;
```